# Problems passing object from JavaScript to Web API

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to upload file from my local machine to SharePoint using JavaScript to ASP.NET MVC Web API call. While trying to pass file object from JavaScript to Web API, I keep on getting errors like Type error, resource not found etc. Can anyone please help on this?

JavaScript code:

```
$scope.Upload = function () {
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert("This browser does not support the HTML5 File APIs");
        return;
    }

    var element = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
    var file = element.files[0];
    //var folderStructure = "/PublishingImages/Lists/Featured%20Stories/";
    var parts = element.value.split("\\");
    var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
    filename1 = fileName;
    var descriptionName = fileName;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var indentifier = '';

    //url = encodeURI(url);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        UploadDocs(e.target.result, fileName);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        alert(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

}

function UploadDocs(str, file) {
    var url = webApiUrl + "api/Registration/UploadFileToDocmentLibrary";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(str),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,

        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.fileData);
            console.log('Success');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('fail');
        }

    });
}
```

Web API code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void UploadFileToDocmentLibrary(HttpPostedFile uploadFile)
    {
     //code to upload to sharepoint
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stringifying an array buffer isn't going to give you any useful data.
Also I believe HttpPostedFile expects a file as multipart/formdata not json.
So you should be using a FormData object to achieve this.

```
$scope.Upload = function () {
    if (!window.FormData) {
        alert("This browser does not support the HTML5 XH2 APIs");
        return;
    }

    var element = document.getElementById("uploadInput");
    var file = element.files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append(element.name, file);

    var url = webApiUrl + "api/Registration/UploadFileToDocmentLibrary";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,//WHY :(

        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.fileData);
            console.log('Success');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('fail');
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this tomorrow. Also, I also tried passing an`object` as the parameter type as well in the C# code, but it still threw a type exception. Since I believe object can accept anything, do you ave an idea of why didn't it work?